# random number in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

`int randomNumber = (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1) * (10 - 0) + 0;`

is the code I'm using, it is getting a random number, but is getting the SAME random combination every time?

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you casting the return-value of `rand()` to `double`? Worse, why are you C-casting? Why is that mouthful arithmetics there, of subtracting zero and adding zero? Just to be clear, the idiomatic use of `rand()` is `int r=rand()%(ubound-lbound)+lbound;` but only if the lower bound isn't zero. If it is, you might as well leave it out.

Comment: @WilhelmTell of Purple-Magenta: What you propose is certainly not idiomatic. Many common pseudo-random number generators are significantly less random in their low order bits than the high order bits. For many values of `ubound-lbound` using modulus can result in significant non-random patterns being generated. Without specific knowledge of the implementation it is much safer to use division and use the randomness of the high order bits.

Answer (score 6):

Try to seed it with a different value each time.

```
srand(time(0))
```

Comment: `srand(getpid())` can also be used. you need to include `ctime` for `time()`

Comment: @N or arguably better-yet, `srand(time(0)^getpid())`.

Comment: They say `srand(time(0))` will do for most cases, but sometimes it isn't good enough. For example, if you write a standard Unix commandline tool where your application starts and (often) quits relatively fast then you need a more sophisticated seed. To see the problem, in Bash try something like the following: `for i in $(seq 10); do ./a.out; done` (where `a.out` is your executable's name). You will see you (most of the times) get the same value. The reason is that the shell executes the program (10 times) so fast that the program gets the same seed for `time(0)`.

Comment: So one solution in this case would be like @N suggests, to use `getpid()` from the `unistd.h` header. On Windows I think it's `_getpid()` from the `process.h` header. Another approach is to read a byte from /dev/urandom on Unix; in Windows you'd need to jump through a number hoops to get this random functionality. The former approach is much simpler and should get the job done. The latter approach is theoretically more solid but is more sophisticated, especially if you cross-compile between Windows and Unix.